# HCF4021BE usage w/ uC

Tags: microcontroller, shift-register

http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dlmain/Datasheets-30/DSA-599035.pdf

The above datasheet is useless to me. (I do know my way around a datasheet somewhat, though)

1) Can someone explain how the heck you operate this thing?

2) Can this thing source current?

3) I see the data and clock pins, but where's the latch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain how the heck you operate this thing?

Clock goes up and the serial input is latched in and the other bits all move over 1. Just like the truth table says.

Or it can work in parallel, also just like the truth table says.

> Can this thing source current?

Nothing worth talking about, just like most CD4k chips. Stick to 74HC/LVC if you need current.

> I see the data and clock pins, but where's the latch?

Latch? [We don't need no stinking latch!](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135155/there-is-no-latch-pin-on-mc74hc164a-shift-register)

Comment: how much mA CAN a pin source, then?

Comment: It's right there on page 4, under I_OH. 2.4mA minimum, 6.8mA typical at 15V supply. Less at lower supply voltages.

Comment: (Assuming 6.8mA is sufficient for an LED) So I'd just set clock high and input a bit to drive an led? (Then of course lower the clock)

Comment: The thing about that 6.8mA current is that you need to be able to drive the input to 11V in order to get it. If you're trying to interface with a 5V MCU there's no way you'll get it. And at 5V supply you only get 1mA of current. But you'd do it the other way around regardless; set the bit and then clock it in.